# Background doesn't fill the height of the window

Tags: css, background, angular-material

the background image of my web doesn't fill all the height of the window when there isn't enough content, here is a example:

Without content:

[image]

With content:

[image]

here is the app.component.html:

```html
<body>
  <!-- Background -->
  <div class="bg">
    <!-- nav -->
    <app-navbar></app-navbar> 

    <!-- Logo -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <img width="200" alt="BookCloud Logo" [routerLink]="['/books']" src="../assets/logo3.png">
    </div>

    <!-- App -->
    <div class="container">
        <app-alert></app-alert>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

and here is the app.component.css:

```css
.container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

img {
  outline: none;
}

html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

.bg{
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  background: url('../assets/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

What im doing wrong? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You css should be

```
.bg{
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  background: url('../assets/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

If that doesn't work, change `.bg` to `body`.

Comment: Thanks! Now the start page is fine, but it does not work in the components in which you have to scroll, as soon as you scroll the background image stops filling as shown in the images

Comment: Nevermind i fixed it adding overflow: auto; Thanks!